# Nameref refers to section title instead of theorem title

Tags: ntheorem, nameref

I've seen similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6821032), but the answer was posted in 2011, stating that it was due to the fact that the used nameref version was obsolete. I have to use Overleaf for my document and I don't have access (I think) to the version it is using. However, I hope Overleaf does not embed a 13 yeas-old obsolete version of the package.

A MWE is here:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[hyperref, standard, thmmarks]{ntheorem}

\begin{document}
\section{My section}
\begin{Definition}[My definition]
    \label{definition:mine}
    That's my definition.
\end{Definition}
Reference : \nameref{definition:mine}
\end{document}
```

Nameref shows the hyperlink as "My section" instead of "My definition". Using the accepted answer of the post I've put above did not change this. What may be the cause of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see ntheorem doesn't set `\@currentlabelname`. You could set it yourself:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[hyperref, standard,thmmarks]{ntheorem}

\begin{document}
\section{My section}

\tracingmacros=1 
\begin{Definition}[My definition]
\makeatletter\def\@currentlabelname{My definition}\makeatother
    \label{definition:mine}
    That's my definition.
\end{Definition}
Reference : \nameref{definition:mine}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks it works! As far as I'm concerned, this is enough for me, but isn't this the kind of things nameref should be able to handle by itself?

Comment: no, this is something that packages like ntheorem should handle. If they want that nameref (or some other reference system) can catch the title, they should set it.